# What is a good side dish for a freshly boiled lobster?

Tags: pairing, serving-suggestion, lobster

I plan to boil a fresh lobster.
Serving it only with melted butter and lemon seems like not enough.
What would be a good side dish for it?

Comment: Is this not a recipe request?

Comment: @Katie: It's highly open-ended but at the moment we don't have a policy on "serving suggestion" questions. This isn't actually asking how to make the lobster, it's asking what to serve *with* it. In theory, at least, there is a limited number of "standard" accompaniments to go with any main course.

Comment: In the meantime, we have created such a policy. "What goes with X" type of questions get closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want side dishes that will not overcome the taste of the lobster.  Steamed or grilled asparagus with just the barest drizzle of olive oil and coarse salt immediately come to my mind. Add a nice risotto (mushroom?) then send me an invitation.

Comment: Grilled asparagus and fried portobello mushrooms were really nice as a side for lobster. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure someone should suggest a lightly dressed salad.

I think it might go with mashed sweet potato with lots of pepper!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest anything that you can grab easily and is not difficult to eat.  You are going to have to get dirty cracking the lobster, so why not get some corn kernels on your face? Growing up in New England our lobster dinner included sweet corn on the cob and cornbread.  (The butter can be used on all of it!)

Also, if you want some greens, maybe some steamed broccoli?

In terms of flavors, are you going to just do a salted water boil or maybe add some old bay?  you can even add bay leaves to the water.  If you are adding flavors to the lobster while boiling, think of how those would go with the sides.

Answer (score 1):

I always like it when breads are served with lobster!

Answer (score 1):

Lobster is really popular in North Western France.  I've seen it served there with crawfish cocktails and oysters; something like [this](http://www.spox.systems/seafood.jpg).

You can also just keep it down to earth and simple.  In New England I used to eat lobster with french fries.  Not quite worthy of Brittany, but yummy all the same.

Comment: Sadly link now dead.

Answer (score 1):

Bread, garlic butter, salad, maybe grilled potatoes and asparagus (not my favourite food, but the neutral taste and texture would go with the subtlety of lobster).

Bread's probably essential to neutralise the fat in the butter.